# users and usermeta table

Tags: users, user-meta

Is it mandatory for each user to have entries in usermeta table as well or it's optional? Recently, I came across a wordpress database which has thousands of users in user table however only a few of them have entries in usermeta table.

I am wondering in what scenario this could have happened as it doesn't look like those entries were manually removed from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install a fresh wordpress setup on your local machine and then have a look at `wp_usersmeta table .` It contains meta(additional) information for each user.You (admin) can also make data entry specific to any user by this function `update_user_meta()` in usermeta table. and retrive the same using `get_user_meta()` funciton.

All fields for all users are not necessary. meta keys can be user specific also.

defaults meta key entries for admin in wordpress 3.6 --

```
first_name
last_name 
nickname 
description 
rich_editing 
comment_shortcuts
admin_color
use_ssl 
show_admin_bar_front
wp_capabilities
wp_user_level 
dismissed_wp_pointers
show_welcome_panel
wp_dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id
managenav-menuscolumnshidden 
metaboxhidden_nav-menus 
nav_menu_recently_edited
closedpostboxes_page 
metaboxhidden_page 
metaboxhidden_page  
wp_user-settings wp_user-settings-time
```

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't answer my question. Are there any meta keys which are mandatorily created when a wordpress user is created? For example, type of user - subscriber, editor or admin?

Comment: yes there are a few .. thats why i suggested you to install a fresh copy of wordpress and lookup in the usermeta table . you will get to know the default meta keys which are created for each user

Comment: Great, thanks. So it implies there are indeed some meta keys which will be created everytime a user is created.

Comment: yes :) and welcome

Comment: I don't understand why there is not a module that can do this yet...